# Wordpress ACF Повторитель в повторителе

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне нужно вывести повторитель в повторителе. Но код не доконца правильно работает. Я не могу понять причину. Переискал в интернете, но не нашел ничего что бы мне помогло

```html
<div class="footer-content__column-lists">

  <?php $main_menu = get_field( 'footer_menu_list','option' ); //Главный повторитель
            //option это не обязательный параметр, он показывает что настройка находяится в отдельном элементе меню 

                foreach( $main_menu as $element ): ?>

  <div class="footer-content__column">
    <h5 class="footer-content__column-title" style="color: red">
      <?php echo $element['footer_menu_list_title']; ?>
    </h5>

    <?php 
                            if($element['footer_menu_list']): ?>

    <div class="footer-content__column-item">

      <?php foreach ( $elementor['footer_menu_list_items'] as $subitem ): ?>
      <ul class="footer-nav">
        <li class="footer-nav__item">
          <a href="" class="footer-nav__link">
            <?php echo $subitem['footer_menu_item']; ?>
          </a>
        </li>

        <?php endforeach;?>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <?php endif; endforeach; ?>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Выводит только title, Из первого повторителя

Comment: А что за `endif;` перед `endforeach;`? Не вижу начала условия.

Comment: После тега h5 Начало